# jQuery/CSS: Set dynamic width by content, avoid inheritance

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a slider based on jQuery. There's a "display window" div of 960px, and another div inside that holds all the content. The content has a dynamic width and I want to be able to retrieve this size so that the slider script knows exactly how far to scroll on each side.

After loading the content (just plain PHP queries that outputs HTML), for some reason the div inside persists on heriting the other div's width, and I end up getting a 960px content (even if the content takes up more space). I've set the div to "inherit: none !important" and in jQuery I am looking for a way to maybe set an initial width, then reset it and look for the total width of the div. How would you approach this?

```
var contentWidth = $('#content').width();
$('#content').css('width', contentWidth); // Does not help resetting
alert ("#content width is " + contentWidth); // Gives me 960
```

Answer (score 2):

To reset the width, you have to remove the `width` CSS property first *and* adjust the `display` property:

By default, a DIV element has the `display: block` style, which causes the element to take the full width. Temporary change the `display` property, in order to obtain the true minimum width:

```
var display = $("#content").css("display"); //Get current display style
$("#content").css({display:"inline-block", width:""});

//Calculate width
var contentWidth = $('#content').width();

//Return display style, set new width
$('#content').css({width: contentWidth, display: display});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It still gives me the inherited width (tried changing the container and the contentWidth shows it's width every time unless I set something specific for the content div).

Comment: My solution should work. Show your whole source code (link/fiddle/in OP).

Comment: Ah you're right, it works. Tried it with JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/juDRE/2/. So there's obviously something with my stylesheet that prevents me from retrieving the real value.

Comment: Is there any way to reset the size? Like for example setting an initial width of 9999em, then get the real width...?

Comment: Wait, it's not working. Check my JSFiddle link and try and add some more content.

Comment: The code is working as intended. I see, however, that you're using `float:left` (`.sample_slide`). This declaration causes your `#content` div to take as much width as possible. Add `clear:both` to `.sample_slide` if you don't want this effect. See **http://jsfiddle.net/juDRE/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
$("#content").width(contentWidth);
```

Comment: Not really sure how that would help...?

Comment: Have you tried? It is a different way to set the width, and has worked for many other askers.

Comment: I assume you mean first retrieving the width by "var contentWidth = $('#content').width();", then using the variable like above? Tried it and it didn't help.