# Absolute layout of an element that will overflow but is only constrained on 3 sides

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to cerate a layout where a div that is the scroll container is absolutely positioned on three sides ( left,right and bottom ) but sizes dynamically with it's sibling container above.  Both the scroll container and the sibling are in a fixed dimension container. I have made a jsfiddle which demonstrates my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/HKu4j/4

If you follow the click instructions there you will see that when you click the top container after clicking the second container it resizes which ideally would push the top of div.myscroll down. This doesn't happen since div.myscroll has top set to 20px; Is there some way with the new CSS3 flexible box layouts to make this work ? I am looking for a solution that uses CSS rather than setting geometry dimensions explicitly with javascipt as I have done in the past.

Comment: Your question looks very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294543/overflow-with-absolute-relative-positioning-layout. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to modify that to my use:  http://jsfiddle.net/xRr7e/2/

Comment: Someone has asked a similar question, you might benefit from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294543/overflow-with-absolute-relative-positioning-layout

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible using css alone.

Try this jQuery dynamic width setting example: [jQuery/CSS: Set dynamic width by content, avoid inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666183/jquery-css-set-dynamic-width-by-content-avoid-inheritance)